# File access denied *after* burning to disc

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, compact-disc, optical-media

After using the built-in CD burner on WIN2k8 R2 to burn files downloaded by a regular user, all of the burned files seem to have changed the ownership to Administrator, since the regular user gets the "Access Denied" when tries to view them (but is allowed to make a copy).

Cannot reproduce since I don't have spare CDs anymore, but I think it only happened after the last backup session.

I can change the permissions back, but I would like to know how to stop this from happening.

Comment: Try changing the file permissions. Will it let you?

Comment: Yes, I can change the permissions as a regular user. But I kind of knew that.

Comment: @Chipperyman I've rephrased the question